# How to get comma-separated values in Linq?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the query below:

```
var users = (from a in dc.UserRoles
                             join u in dc.Users on a.intUserId equals u.ID
                             join r in dc.Roles on a.intRoleId equals r.ID
                             where r.intClientId == clientID
                             select new UserRoleDetail
                             {
                                 ID = a.ID,
                                 intUserId = a.intUserId,
                                 intRoleId = a.intRoleId,
                                 Name =u.FullName, //Here I need comma separated values.
                                 intAssignedById = a.intAssignedById,
                                 RoleName = r.vchName,
                                 Function = u.vchFunction
                             });
```

I require all the values of `"Name =u.FullName"` to be comma-separated in a single record group by intRoleId. I mean for every role I need all the usernames in a sigle record comma separated. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out the [IEnumerable.Aggregate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) method.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use it. I am new to Linq.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861202/linq-query-with-subquery-as-comma-separated-values for an example.