# Rails: saving a range of values in a single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a form where a user can make a workout. The workout `has_many` exercises that have the following parameters:

- name: Bench Press
- sets: 3
- repetitions: 12
- rest_time: 60 seconds

What I’m trying to do is store multiple values for repetitions and rest time, one for each set, but without having to use a join table to store the data, if possible. So for example I want to do something like this:

- name: Bench Press
- sets: 3
- repetitions: 12, 8, 6
- rest_time: 60, 60, 30

Is that possible? I can’t find anything on this topic – maybe I’m asking the question wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “join table”, but I think the standard method does not use one. Since this is a many-to-one relationship, not a many-to-many relationship, you don’t need a specific table just to hold joins – just one table for workouts and one for repetitions, for example. That uses a join, but not a join table.

Comment: You probably don’t want to try to create your own method of storing multiple values in one record such as parsing comma-separated values in a string – that would just destroy the advantage in using a database, and force you to reimplement lots of things.

Comment: I was thinking that since a workout has_many exercises, and each exercise has a sets field, a repetitions field, and a rest_time field, I thought it would be easiest to just specify the number of sets an exercise has, then use something like ActiveModel serialize to store the different values of repetitions for each set for the exercise.

Comment: My other thought was to create a join table that was exercise_sets, and store each set with it's specific information for each exercise in each workout, but that seemed much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate table for exercise sets, rather than trying to store a serialized list in a single column. See these other answers for reasoning:

- [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/578288)
- [How to store a list in a column of a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3070426/578288)

Creating a separate table just to hold exercise sets may seem unnecessarily complicated, but it’s how relational databases work. By storing the data in a separate table, you can use ActiveRecord to easily handle the data, such as calculating the maximum number of repetitions or total time spent resting. If you stored values as a list, you'd have to write unnecessary custom code to do things like that.

The linked answers go into more detail, with more reasons to use a separate table.

Here’s what I think the schema would be for the `exercise_set` table:

- `id` (e.g. 455, 466, 468) – primary key
- `workout_id` (e.g. 288, 288, 288) – foreign key
- `set_number` (e.g. 1, 2, 3)
- `repetitions` (e.g. 12, 8, 6)
- `rest_time` (e.g. 60, 60, 30)

Comment: You're right. I'll do that. Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm glad I didn't spend too much time on the other approach.