# How to use List of model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to do like this:

```
Class conversation(models.Model):
      user1, user2 =; # this is from User table
      messages = List(Message) # where Message is also a model

Class Message(models.Model):
      sender, reciever ; # this is user ID from User Model
      ...... # many other attribute
      message = TextField()
```

This is only a pseudo code. Anybody, please explain to me how to do this.
If possible, give me a suitable tutorial link related to this. Thanks.

Comment: Why not add conversation as a foreign key in Message model?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use foreign key. I just want to store a list of messages in conversation table. Can I do like that????

Comment: If `Message` is a model, then you have to use a foreign key. If it some other bit of data, you could look at ArrayField to start arrays of text https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: Not Django related, but SQL, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070384/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-column-of-a-database-table

Comment: Can we use like this:
`conversation = {
user1 = A,
user2 = B,
Messages=[ 
{message1},{message2},{message3}
]}
`

Comment: If you added a foreign key in Message like this `conversation = ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')` , you could do something like this to get messages from a conversation: `conversation.messages.all()`.

Comment: ok. Thanks, @DanielReinoso :). Can you provide me useful links to do this? Exclude djangoproject.com.

Comment: It's as easy as I said above, what else do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class Conversation(models.Model):
      user1, user2 =; # this is from User table
      ...... # many other attribute

Class Message(models.Model):
      sender, reciever ; # this is user ID from User Model
      ...... # many other attribute
      conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
```

To see the messages of a conversation instance, you can follow the relationship backward like this

```
conversation = Conversation.objects.get(...)
conversation_messages = conversation.messages.all()
```