# MYSQL REGEXP with JSON array

Tags: mysql, json, regex

I have an JSON string stored in the database and I need to SQL COUNT based on the WHERE condition that is in the JSON string. I need it to work on the MYSQL 5.5.

The only solution that I found and could work is to use the REGEXP function in the SQL query.

Here is my JSON string stored in the **custom_data** column:

```
{"language_display":["1","2","3"],"quantity":1500,"meta_display:":["1","2","3"]}
```

https://regex101.com/r/G8gfzj/1

I now need to create a SQL sentence:

```
SELECT COUNT(..) WHERE custom_data REGEXP '[HELP_HERE]'
```

The condition that I look for is that the **language_display** has to be either 1, 2 or 3... or whatever value I will define when I create the SQL sentence.

So far I came here with the REGEX expression, but it does not work:

```
(?:\"language_display\":\[(?:"1")\])
```

Where 1 is replaced with the value that I look for. I could in general look also for "1" (with quotes), but it will also be found in the meta_display array, that will have different values.

I am not good with REGEX! Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to check whether the array in `language_display` contains 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: Yes. But also any other integer that would be included in array, not only 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following regex to get matches on your test string

```
\"language_display\":\[(:?\"[0-9]\"\,)*?\"3\"(:?\,\"[0-9]\")*?\]
```

https://regex101.com/ is a free online regex tester, it seems to work great.  Start small and work big.

Sorry it doesn't work for you.  It must be failing on the non greedy '*?' perhaps try without the '?'

Have a look at how to serialize this data, with an eye to serializing the language display fields.
[How to store a list in a column of a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070384/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-column-of-a-database-table)

Even if you were to get your idea working it will be slow as fvck. Better off to process through each row once and generate something more easily searched via sql.  Even a field containing the comma separated list would be better.

Comment: It does seem to work in the pcre but it does not work with REGEXP in SQL, since there is no full pcre syntax supported. The error I get is: Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp. Any workaround?