# Create an entity call "Team" that has a Manager and collection of Marketing Officers using "User" entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I just want to confirm whether this is a good approach to model an entity as bellow and what are the basics rules that it brakes?
By doing so do I need to do anything OnModelCreating?

**Usecase:** There are two types of users. One is Manger, the other one is the Marketing Officer. Then the Manager wants to create his team.

So I have modeled it as follows.
**User and Role entities**

```
public class User { 
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public string UserName {get; set;} 
    public virtual Role Designation  {get; set;} 
}

public class Role { 
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string RoleName {get; set;}
}
```

**Then composed the Team entity.**

```
public class Team { 
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public int ManagerId {get; set;} 
    public virtual User Manager {get; set;} 

    public virtual ICollection<User> MarketingOfficers  {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070384/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-column-of-a-database-table

Comment: There are no obvious problems with that model.  And as for whether it requires any additional configuration, you should test and see.