# Could not determine type for: java.util.List for List<String>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, database-design

I am new to Spring services. I want to create a table in database which has one column with data type List.

```java
@Entity 
@Table(name = "employees") 
public class Employees { 
    @Id 
    @Column(name= Id) 
    private long id; 

    @Column(name= Name) 
    private String name; 

    @Column(name= Skills) 
    private List<String> skills;

    //getter setters for all 
}
```

But on run I am getting error Could not determine type for: java.util.List for List

How can I resolve it? (I tried oneToMany annotation but I think I did not use it in right way)

Comment: You can not save a list like that in a relational SQL DB. You have to define some kind of xToMany association (and define a Skills entity). For how to do it refer to the other stackoverflow questions or tutorials.

Comment: you cannot save list as column , However if you want to save it as comma sperated strings values in coloum take a look at :https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-array-java-list/

Comment: @Noshaf that would be possible buuuut that would not really be best practice
 as it violates one of the basic principles of relational databases (first normal form).
Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070384/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-column-of-a-database-table for more information why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Can you please refer me link for example if any

Comment: @lugiorgi i totally agree with you this is not good practice .it is  just a work around. It depend on requirment what suits you

Comment: @ShitalPatil with minimal research effort I found https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many. This should get you started.

Comment: Another option, if you decide the current route you're taking isn't what you need, is to use a non-relational database

Comment: I have to use relational data base

Comment: Use an `@ElementCollection` to map it to a table. You cannot map, without additional converters, map a collection to a single column.