# Replacing comma separated integers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I have the following tables:

Employee:

| Id | NAME | Qualification | Experience(yrs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aaron | Eng | 2 |
| 2 | Jacob | CS | 3 |
| 3 | Jehan | Art | 1 |
| 4 | Jenny | Math | 7 |

Task:

| Task_Name | Emp_id | duration(mins) | Wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| clean | 1,3 | 200 | 50 |
| wash | 4 | 300 | 200 |
| decor | 1,2,4 | 250 | 300 |
| errands | 2,4 | 150 | 150 |

I would like to write an oracle query which returns the following output:

Task_responsbility:

| Task_Name | Employee | duration(mins) | Wage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| clean | Aaron,Jehan | 200 | 50 |
| wash | Jenny | 300 | 200 |
| decor | Aaron,Jacob,Jenny | 250 | 300 |
| errands | Jacob,Jenny | 150 | 150 |

I need the `Emp_ids` to be replaced by `employee_names`

Can someone please let me know how to go about this ?

Comment: What are the definiton of tables? My point that I want to go actually is that how do you store values in "Emp_id" column?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Avoiding comma-separated lists is kind of the point of relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT task_name,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG(e.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
                  ORDER BY INSTR(',' || t.emp_id || ',', ',' || e.id || ',')
                )
         FROM   Employee e
         WHERE  INSTR(',' || t.emp_id || ',', ',' || e.id || ',') > 0
       ) AS emp_names,
       duration,
       wage
FROM   task t
```

*Note: this will output the names in the same order as the `id` values in your list. If you want to order alphabetically then you can use `ORDER BY e.name`,*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee(Id, NAME, Qualification, Experience) AS
SELECT 1, 'Aaron', 'Eng',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Jacob', 'CS',   3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Jehan', 'Art',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Jenny', 'Math', 7 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Task (Task_Name, Emp_id, duration, Wage) AS
SELECT 'clean',   '1,3',   200,  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'wash',    '4',     300, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'decor',   '1,2,4', 250, 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'errands', '2,4',   150, 150 FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | TASK_NAME | EMP_NAMES | DURATION | WAGE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | clean | Aaron,Jehan | 200 | 50 |
> | wash | Jenny | 300 | 200 |
> | decor | Aaron,Jacob,Jenny | 250 | 300 |
> | errands | Jacob,Jenny | 150 | 150 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a138263a08c1680af4cd881723f952a0)*

Answer (score 1):

You should not store your id s(int) in "emp_id"(presumably varchar(x)) column. Check out: [How to store a list in a column of a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070384/how-to-store-a-list-in-a-column-of-a-database-table)

You should store each emp_id in another row in your task table to comply first normal form.

```
create table emp(
id number(10),
name varchar(30),
Qualification varchar(30),
Experience number(10));

create table task(
Task_Name varchar(30),
id number(10),
duration number(10),
wage number(10));

INSERT ALL
   INTO emp VALUES (1,'Aaron','Eng', 2 )
   INTO emp VALUES (2,'Jacob','CS',  3 )
   INTO emp VALUES (3,'Jehan','Art', 1 )
   INTO emp VALUES (4,'Jenny','Math', 7 )
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

INSERT ALL
INTO task VALUES('clean', 1, 200, 50 )
INTO task VALUES('clean', 3, 200, 50 )
INTO task VALUES('wash', 4, 300, 200)
INTO task VALUES('decor', 1, 250, 300)
INTO task VALUES('decor', 2, 250, 300)
INTO task VALUES('decor', 4, 250, 300)
INTO task VALUES('errands', 2, 150, 150)
INTO task VALUES('errands', 4, 150, 150)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

After this point joining tables are easy and no need complex functions:

```
with tab1 as (select * from emp e join task t
on e.id=t.id)
select task_name,
 LISTAGG(e.name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
                  ORDER BY e.name) name_list, max(duration) duration, max(wage) wage from tab1 e group by task_name;
```

[DB Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9b0f6c8b66b22a826f3df42fba74adb6)

Comment: While the suggestion not to store emp IDs as a list in a string is appropriate and good, you still got it wrong. `ON emp.id = task.id`? Really? Why should you want an employee ID to match a task ID? A task and an employee are two different things. The relation between task and employee is an m:n relation, so you need three tables: task, emp, emp_task.

Comment: Hi, just read and understand construction of table and the question and it' s data. The "id" column in the task table contains the "emp_id" data. I just pick "id" for the notation. Really? It is just a comment to make a comment. You need a coffee @ThorstenKettner. Instead of complainıng such a fuss you can just rename "id" column in "task" table to "emp_id".

Comment: Okay, sorry, I didn't see it was just a misnomer. And obviously you didn't notice either that you were mistaken in naming the column. When I see `emp.id = task.id`, alarm bells ring. I thought this was the same with every programmer :-) Your solution is still wrong. You are showing an 1:n relation where it must be an m:n relation.

Comment: Oh sorry again. It is not a proper 1:n relation your are showing, but a malformed m:n relation missing one table and thus violating database normalization. Anyway, it would be good, if you got this straight. You need three tables as mentioned. For I generally prefer your answer that the data model should be changed over an answer that shows how to muddle through with the bad original data model.

Comment: It is a proper one and it is an aggregation. If you think otherwise you could add your answer, of course if you had got this straight. Yet, no; still continue to make fuss. No need to waste time with @ThorstenKettner :).

Answer (score 1):

Umut TEKİN has asked me to write a separate answer in which I build up on their suggestion to change the data model. So, here it is...

You have already been told in the request comments and in Umut's answer that your data model is not good. It violates the first normal form, so to say the base rule on how to build a relational database. Don't store multiple values in a single column. This can make querying the data more complicated and it prevents the DBMS from ensuring data consistency.

You are showing an m:n relation. One task can relate to many employees, and one employee can be involved with many tasks. For an m:n relation you need three tables, in your case:

- employee (employee_id, name, qualification, experience_years)
- task(task_id, task_name, duration_mins, wage)
- task_employee (task_id, employee_id)

The IDs are the tables' primary keys of course and you need two foreign keys in the task_employee table to the other tables.

Using this model doesn't mean that the query you want becomes super-short or extremely simple. But it means that the DBMS can ensure that you cannot combine a task with invalid employee IDs any longer. And the DBMS can probably access the data much quicker, because it can use indexes.

Here is what a query could look like:

```
select t.task_name, emp.employees, t.duration_mins, t.wage
from task t 
left join
(
  select te.task_id, listagg(e.name, ', ') within group (order by e.name) as employees
  from task_employee te
  join employee e using (employee_id)
  group by te.task_id
) emp using (task_id);
```

Comment: Thank you, again you should read and understand the question and the data... Start with: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization Especially(Satisfying 5NF). I just questioned myself and look what I found: stackoverflow.com/questions/27268711/… You did same mistake here: stackoverflow.com/questions/59380123/…

Comment: @Umut TEKİN: I've read the question again and again, and I must admit that I don't know what you are trying to point me to. Sorry. The tables I am suggesting seem to be in 5NF alright. And I still think my old answer you linked to is correct. You asked me to write this answer when I told you that your own solution violates datebase normalization (2NF). I did so. I don't understand what you think should be different...

Comment: ... Why don't you just correct your own answer to offer the OP the best of help? Just get your tables in 2NF and let me see how this is different from my tables. OP and future readers may benefit a lot from this.

Comment: I did...I knew it was a pointless idea to say that read it again and again. Obviously, you don' t want to... Starting from your first comment you just evaluate the book by its cover. Thanks again, no need to waste time here :).